# Flink async IO throwing timeout error when orderedWait but not when unorderedWait

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-flink

So here is the code of the async data stream:

```
DataStream<ReturnObject> asyncResultStream = AsyncDataStream.orderedWait(
            dataFromMap,
            new CustomAsyncConnector(),
            5,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
10).startNewChain().uid("thisCustomId");
```

Now when I run it as an unorderedWait the timeout exception is never triggered, but when I run it as an orderedWait after maybe a few hundred records something triggers the timeout.

Now if my understanding is correct, all making it an orderedWait changes is that the async datastream just releases the received data in the order in which it calls them. So even if the 3rd call on the queue gets data back before the 1st call does, it won't be released until the 1st call receives its data and it is released. 
So I know (assume) that the first call is receiving data before the timeout time when the async datastream is running as an unorderedWait since I can run through all the data and not have a timeout. So the other option I can think of is even though the 3rd call received data, because it isn't released within the timeout period, it throws a timeout exception. But that doesn't seem right to me.

I should also mention that there is a second map function immediately after the async datastream that uses its data and that second map function is significantly slower, so it is causing serious back pressure up stream. Granted this still doesn't make the unorderedWait async datastream throw any timeout error, but I figured it could be relevant.

Am I missing something or can someone just shed some light as to what might be the true issue?

Thanks for any help in advance!

**UPDATE** 
This is not throwing a timeout error anymore, but I am running it at a parallelism of 3 so that could just be enough for it to handle and not get backed up. However this doesn't really answer the question since that suggests that if something is in the queue and has been completed but not released that it throws a timeout error, and I am not sure if that is true or just my assumption. And if it is true, if that is the desired functionality or not.

Comment: Your question is most likely answered by http://stackoverflow.com/a/43754977/4815083

Comment: Thanks @TillRohrmann that does answer this.